# how to manage permission table in django admin

Tags: python, django, web, django-admin

[image]

When I use `django admin`, I can get `Groups`, `Users` management entrance on the dashboard? How can I get `Permission` table management entrance as pictures shows above?
I am using django 1.4 . thx for ur time.

**EDITED:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, ContentType

class PermissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [  
        (None,          {'fields': ['name','codename']}),  

    ]  
    list_display = ('name', 'codename')      

class ContentTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [  
        (None,          {'fields': ['app_label','model']}),  
        ('More info',   {'fields': ['name','codename'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),  

    ]  
    list_display = ('app_label', 'model')         

admin.site.register(Permission, PermissionAdmin)
admin.site.register(ContentType, ContentTypeAdmin)
```

After edited, I got.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'ContentTypeAdmin.fieldsets[1][2]['fields']' refers to field 'codename' that is missing from the form.
```

ContentType could `onetomany` to Permission. How to deal with to these two model in admin?
It works fine before I add:

```
('More info',   {'fields': ['name','codename'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
```

**EDIT2:**
[image]

Comment: With what do you mean "Permission" table?

Comment: That is a model in django, like `Groups` and `Users`, and a table in database. @RickardZachrisson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how you imagined the ui to behave or look but you can do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

class PermissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Permission
    fields = ['name']

admin.site.register(Permission, PermissionAdmin)
```

Perhaps you can pick it up from there and tweak it as you wish.

Comment: It works, thx. I have edited my code. but when I trying to manager `Permission` and `ContentType` at same time, I got new problem, because of onetomany relationship between them. Do you know what happened about the code? @Rickard Zachrisson

Comment: What do you mean with "same time"?

Comment: It means that I can see two models' data in the same web page, when I try to add or change data. Look the picture in `EDIT2`. `Job` and `Location` are two model. `Job` has a foreign key which references to `Location`. So I can select `Location` when I add jobs into `Job`. How to do that? @Rickard Zachrisson

Comment: Got it. I lost a field in PermissionAdmin. thx Rickard Zachrisson.